# Can Triggered Send work with Lists/DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

Can we send a Triggered Email to a List or DE ? On some trigger, I want to send email to several subscribers immediately. How can I achieve that?
Can Triggered send help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Script Activity in JavaScript:

1. Retrieve the Data Extension records in an array
2. Loop through the array and trigger the send definition for each item

Now it's just a matter of running the Script Activity.